# Enumerate - Don't use localized alphabet

Tags: enumerate, locale

I have an `enumerate` environment defined as:

```
\begin{enumerate}[\hspace{0.5cm} a)]
    \item blablabla
\end{enumerate}
```

And as intended it enumerates using letters. But, since my document is in spanish, after the `n` it enumerates using an `ñ` ('eɲe' or 'énye', phonetically). I want it to use the standard alphabet (`ñ` is not ussually used to enumerate in our culture). I don't really want to use `\stepcounter{enumi}` since it's a machine generated tex code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to grab with `\let` the original `\@alph` macro before `babel` comes into action and redefines `\@alph` to provide the specific additions according to the letters of Spanish language.

At the begin of `enumerate` environment this can be changed back to the original (pre-babel) version. However, this would change any occurence of `\@alph` as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\let\@alphorig\@alph
\makeatother
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{%
  \let\@alph\@alphorig
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[\hspace{0.5cm} a)]
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
    \item blablabla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A crude solution is to add the option `es-nolayout`, that also changes other typographical aspects (see `texdoc spanish`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nolayout]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Outer
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Inner
  \item b
  \setcounter{enumii}{12} % just to keep it short
  \item m
  \item n
  \item o
  \item p
  \item q
  \end{enumerate}
\item Outer
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

A more on target approach, just removing “ñ” and “Ñ” from the alphabetical numbering can be obtained with `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@alph}{\~n\or}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@Alph}{\~N\or}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Outer
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Inner
  \item b
  \setcounter{enumii}{12} % just to keep it short
  \item m
  \item n
  \item o
  \item p
  \item q
  \end{enumerate}
\item Outer
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This works also with `enumitem` or `enumerate` features (I suggest using the former package, which is much more powerful and flexible).

[image]

It's a good idea to address a feature request to Javier Bezos, the maintainer of `babel-spanish`.

Comment: I tried an approach where I switch the language with´\begin{otherlanguage}{english}´ for the list. But the special n still appears. Didn't thought that it's so complicated :).

Answer (score 1):

Under [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) you can define the enumeration label. For example, using `\noNalph` as defined below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\noNalph}[1]{\ifnum\value{#1}=15 \refstepcounter{#1}\fi \alph{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\noNalph{enumi})}]
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

In a more general setting, you can also define the sequence of enumeration manually:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\noNalph}[1]{\ifcase\value{#1}% 0
  %   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
  \or a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\or j\or k\or l\or m%
  %  14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
  \or n\or o\or p\or q\or r\or s\or t\or u\or v\or w\or x\or y\or z%
  \else\@ctrerr\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\noNalph{enumi})}]
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
  \item blablabla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```